# How to write a member function whose parameters are changed according to values passed to the constructor? (typescript)

Tags: typescript

Recently I came across a [new feature in Typescript, which allows you to define an `Omit<T,P>` type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215#issuecomment-307871458).

I want use it to define a class, where you pass default values to the constructor, and according to how many default values you passed in the constructor, the amount of values you need to pass to other member function change.

Example code: (which doesn't do what I want, but I hope it makes it more clear)

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({ [P in T]: P } & { [P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>;
type MyOmit<T, K> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, keyof K>>;

type CommonFields = Partial<{
  field1: number;
  field2: string;
}>;

interface func1Params {
  field1: number;
  field2: string;
  field4: string;
}

interface func2Params {
  field1: number;
  field2: string;
  field3: string;
}

class Example<D> {
  constructor(private defaults: D) {};

  func1(params: MyOmit<func1Params, D>) {
   return null;
  }

  func2(params: MyOmit<func2Params, D> ){
   return null;
  }
}

const e = new Example({field1: 4});

e.func1({/* I expect only 'field2' and 'field4' to be acceptable here */})
e.func2({/* I expect only 'field2' and 'field3' to be acceptable here */})
```

Someone knows how to makes this work? to me it seems the issue is from the behavior of `keyof` on a generic type, but maybe there is a way around it.

Any other solution not using the 'Omit' type are also welcome.

Comment: To me it's not clear what you are looking to achieve. Have you looked at Typescript:Rest Parameters denoted by ... https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/rest-parameters.html Does that not achieve what you want already? If not can you elaborate what you want to do.

Comment: I don't think there's a way around this problem currently; `Omit` and company don't seem to work with generics.  Typescript doesn't (yet) have [subtraction types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183), which is what you need.  The only workaround for now I can find is to manually annotate allowed and prohibited keys at the constructor call site, which is burdensome for the programmer.  If you're interested, let me know and I'll put the code as an answer.  Otherwise, good luck.